# How to concatenate a date field data and a time field data of a form in Symfony2 to be saved as a datetime data in a database datetime field ?

Tags: forms, date, symfony, datetime, time

I would like to know how to concatenate a date field data and a time field data of a form in Symfony2 to be saved as a datetime data in a database datetime field. The explanation is as below:

I would like to add two new time fields to the form in this screen shot:

[image]

This is the code of the form (it is in twig and html):

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <title> Wkayet </title>
         <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{asset('bundles/ikprojhome/images/icon-WKAYET.png')}}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('bundles/ikprojhome/css2/css.css')}}"/>
        <script src='{{asset('bundles/ikprojhome/lib/jquery.min.js')}}'></script> 

    </head>
    <body>
    <center>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="header">

            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <table width="100%" height="100%" align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            {% for x in groupe%}
   <form id="EventForm" action='{{path('ikproj_groupe_homepaeventsAdd',{id:x['id']})}}' method="POST" {{ form_enctype(form) }} onsubmit="javascript:parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();">
   <!--<form id="EventForm" action='{{path('ikproj_groupe_homepaeventsAdd',{id:x['id']})}}' method="POST" {{ form_enctype(form) }} >-->
                                {% endfor %}
                                 {{ form_errors(form) }}
                                <table align="center">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="separation"><label for="groupname">Titre</label></td>
                                        <td>
                                     <!--<input id="titre" name="titre" required="required" type="text" size="50"/> -->
                                         <div>
                                            {{ form_errors(form.title) }}

                                            {{ form_widget(form.title) }}
                                           </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="separation"><label for="debut">Début</label></td>
                                        <td><!--<select id="debut" name="debut" class="select"></select>-->
                                            <div>
                                             {{ form_errors(form.startdate ) }}

                                             {{ form_widget(form.startdate ) }}
                                            </div>


                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="separation"><label for="heure_debut">Heure</label></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div>
                                             {{ form_errors(form.starttime ) }}

                                             {{ form_widget(form.starttime ) }}
                                            </div>


                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="separation"><label for="fin">Fin</label></td>
                                        <td><!--<select id="fin" name="fin" class="select"></select>-->
                                            <div>
                                             {{ form_errors(form.enddate ) }}

                                             {{ form_widget(form.enddate ) }}
                                          </div> 

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="separation"><label for="heure_fin">Heure</label></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div>
                                             {{ form_errors(form.starttime ) }}

                                             {{ form_widget(form.starttime ) }}
                                            </div>


                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="separation"><label for="lieu">Lieu</label></td>
                                        <td> <!--<select id="lieu" name="lieu" class="select"></select> -->

                                         <div>
                                           {{ form_errors(form.location) }}

                                         {{ form_widget(form.location , {'attr':{'class':'select '}}) }}
                                          </div>

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td id="description" valign="top" class="separation"><label for="description">Description</label></td>
                                        <td><textarea id="ikproj_groupebundle_eventsgroupe_description" name="ikproj_groupebundle_eventsgroupe[description]" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea> 



                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2" align="center" id="button" valign="bottom"><input class="button" type="submit" value=""/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                         {{form_widget(form._token)}} 
                            </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code of the form class :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
       // ->add('idGroupe')
        ->add('title','text')
        ->add('startdate','date',array(
         'widget' => 'single_text',
         'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',))
        ->add('starttime', 'time', array(
              'input'  => 'datetime',
              'widget' => 'choice',))
        ->add('enddate','date',array(
         'widget' => 'single_text',
         'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',))
        ->add('endtime', 'time', array(
              'input'  => 'datetime',
              'widget' => 'choice',))
        ->add('location','country')
        ->add('description','text')
      //  ->add('partager')
    ;
}
```

This is the code of the entity with which I am dealing:

```
  <?php

namespace Ikproj\GroupeBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * eventsgroupe
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="eventsgroupe")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Ikproj\GroupeBundle\Entity\eventsgroupeRepository")
 */
class eventsgroupe 
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     *
     * @var integer 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Groupe", inversedBy="eventsgroupe")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="admingroupe_id", referencedColumnName="admingroupe_id", nullable=FALSE)
     * @ORM\Column(name="admingroupe_id", type="string", length=255)
     */
     private $idGroupe;

     /**
     *
     * @var integer 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Groupe", inversedBy="eventsgroupe")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idgroupe", referencedColumnName="id_groupe", nullable=FALSE)
     * @ORM\Column(name="idgroupe", type="string", length=255)
     */
     private $idEventGroupe;


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="start", type="datetime")
     */
    private $start;

    /**
     * @var \Date
     */
    private $startdate;

    /**
     * @var \Time
     */
    private $starttime;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="end", type="datetime")
     */
    private $end;

     /**
     * @var \Date
     */
    private $enddate;

    /**
     * @var \Time
     */
    private $endtime;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="location", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $location;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="partager", type="boolean")
     */
    private $partager;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getIdGroupe()
    {
        return $this->idGroupe;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     * @return eventsgroupe
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get startdate
     *
     * @return date 
     */
    public function getStartdate()
    {
        return $this->startdate;
    }

    /**
     * Set startdate
     *
     * @param date $startdate
     * @return eventsgroupe
     */
    public function setStartdate($startdate)
    {
        $this->startdate = $startdate;

        return $this;
    }

     /**
     * Get enddate
     *
     * @return date 
     */
    public function getEnddate()
    {
        return $this->enddate;
    }

    /**
     * Set enddate
     *
     * @param date $enddate
     * @return eventsgroupe
     */
    public function setEnddate($enddate)
    {
        $this->enddate = $enddate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get starttime
     *
     * @return time 
     */
    public function getStarttime()
    {
        return $this->starttime;
    }

    /**
     * Set starttime
     *
     * @param time $starttime
     * @return eventsgroupe
     */
    public function setStarttime($starttime)
    {
        $this->starttime = $starttime;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get endttime
     *
     * @return time 
     */
    public function getEndtime()
    {
        return $this->endttime;
    }

    /**
     * Set endtime
     *
     * @param time $endtime
     * @return eventsgroupe
     */
    public function setEndtime($endtime)
    {
        $this->endtime = $endtime;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set start
     *
     * @param \DateTime $start
     * @return eventsgroupe
     */
    public function setStart($startdate,$starttime)
    {
        //$this->start = $start;
        $this->start.date('yyyy-MM-dd') = $startdate;
        $this->start.time() = $starttime;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get start
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getStart()
    {
        return $this->start;
    }

    /**
     * Set end
     *
     * @param \DateTime $end
     * @return eventsgroupe
     */
    public function setEnd($enddate,$endtime)
    {
        $this->end.date('yyyy-MM-dd') = $enddate;
        $this->end.time() = $endtime;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get end
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getEnd()
    {
        return $this->end;
    }

    /**
     * Set location
     *
     * @param string $location
     * @return eventsgroupe
     */
    public function setLocation($location)
    {
        $this->location = $location;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get location
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getLocation()
    {
        return $this->location;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return eventsgroupe
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set partager
     *
     * @param boolean $partager
     * @return eventsgroupe
     */
    public function setPartager($partager)
    {
        $this->partager = $partager;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get partager
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getPartager()
    {
        return $this->partager;
    }
     public function setIdGroupe($idGroupe)
    {
        $this->idGroupe = $idGroupe;

        return $this;
    }

    public function setIdEventGroupe($idEventGroupe)
    {
        $this->idEventGroupe = $idEventGroupe;

        return $this;
    }
    public function getIdEventGroupe()
    {
        return $this->idEventGroupe;
    }

}
```

And this is the structure of the table with which I am dealing in the database:

field name:              Type:
-----------              -----

id                       int
title                    varchar
start                    datetime
end                      datetime
location                 varchar
description              varchar
admingroupe_id           int
idgroupe                 int
partager                 tinyint

Please, focus on the following part of the entity code:

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="start", type="datetime")
 */
private $start;

/**
 * @var \Date
 */
private $startdate;

/**
 * @var \Time
 */
private $starttime;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="end", type="datetime")
 */
private $end;

 /**
 * @var \Date
 */
private $enddate;

/**
 * @var \Time
 */
private $endtime;
```

And this one too:

```
/**
 * Get startdate
 *
 * @return date 
 */
public function getStartdate()
{
    return $this->startdate;
}

/**
 * Set startdate
 *
 * @param date $startdate
 * @return eventsgroupe
 */
public function setStartdate($startdate)
{
    $this->startdate = $startdate;

    return $this;
}

 /**
 * Get enddate
 *
 * @return date 
 */
public function getEnddate()
{
    return $this->enddate;
}

/**
 * Set enddate
 *
 * @param date $enddate
 * @return eventsgroupe
 */
public function setEnddate($enddate)
{
    $this->enddate = $enddate;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get starttime
 *
 * @return time 
 */
public function getStarttime()
{
    return $this->starttime;
}

/**
 * Set starttime
 *
 * @param time $starttime
 * @return eventsgroupe
 */
public function setStarttime($starttime)
{
    $this->starttime = $starttime;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get endttime
 *
 * @return time 
 */
public function getEndtime()
{
    return $this->endttime;
}

/**
 * Set endtime
 *
 * @param time $endtime
 * @return eventsgroupe
 */
public function setEndtime($endtime)
{
    $this->endtime = $endtime;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Set start
 *
 * @param \DateTime $start
 * @return eventsgroupe
 */
public function setStart($startdate,$starttime)
{
    //$this->start = $start;
    $this->start.date('yyyy-MM-dd') = $startdate;
    $this->start.time() = $starttime;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get start
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getStart()
{
    return $this->start;
}

/**
 * Set end
 *
 * @param \DateTime $end
 * @return eventsgroupe
 */
public function setEnd($enddate,$endtime)
{
    $this->end.date('yyyy-MM-dd') = $enddate;
    $this->end.time() = $endtime;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get end
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getEnd()
{
    return $this->end;
}
```

The problem is that when I run the code, the form does't show and this is what I see:

[image]

So my question is: what is wrong in my code exactly??..is there anyone who has any idea?

Comment: in your form template you add starttime twice instead of starttime once and endtime once. Other than that I don't know your controller logic.

Comment: And you should change the logic of getStartTime() to smth like this: return $this->getStart()->format("H:m:s"); And change your setStart back to setStart(\DateTime $start) because doctrine needs to hydrate the entity that way.